# bash parameter expansion ${parameter##word}

Tags: bash

I'm reading through the apache startup script trying to troubleshoot some problems with my server but at the very beginning there is a parameter expansion I don't really understand.

```
SCRIPTNAME="${0##*/}"
SCRIPTNAME="${SCRIPTNAME##[KS][0-9][0-9]}"
if [ -n "$APACHE_CONFDIR" ] ; then
    if [ "${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}" != "${APACHE_CONFDIR}" ] ; then
            DIR_SUFFIX="${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}"
    else
            DIR_SUFFIX=
    fi
elif [ "${SCRIPTNAME##apache2-}" != "$SCRIPTNAME" ] ; then
    DIR_SUFFIX="-${SCRIPTNAME##apache2-}"
    APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2$DIR_SUFFIX
else
    DIR_SUFFIX=
    APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2
fi
```

I'm just looking for some clarification on what ${parameter##word} construct does because the bash reference manual from [gnu](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) is not clear to me.  The manual defines it like this...

> ${parameter#word} ${parameter##word}
>
> the word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion (see Filename Expansion). If the pattern matches the
>   beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the
>   expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest
>   matching pattern (the ‘#’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the
>   ‘##’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal
>   operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable
>   subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied
>   to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the
>   resultant list.

does this mean that the first line stores an empty string back into `SCRIPTNAME` or am I just way off base?

Comment: The special treatment of `*` in the part of the documentation of `${parameter##word}`  that you highlight is referring to `*` as the `parameter`.  In `SCRIPTNAME="${0##*/}"`, however, the `*` appears as part of the `word`.

Comment: For the record, this parameter expansion is not a GNU extension – it is POSIX.  (Though Bash does have some custom expansion forms, too.) A more canonical definition can be found at [opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line stores the `basename` of the current file in `SCRIPTNAME`. `$0` is (generally) the name of the current script. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in?rq=1) Related question for discussion about it.

The second line then strips a prefix of `K##` or `S##` from the name (assuming `/etc/init.d` link naming conventions.